# Implicit conversion between Scala.Long and Java.lang.Long in collections

Tags: java, scala, implicit-conversion, value-class

I'm using JavaConverters to go from a Java SortedSet to a Vector.

```
    val lines = function.getInstructions.asScala.toVector
```

My getInstructions function returns an ArrayList of java.lang.Long, yet the consuming code requires Scala.Long. Is there a way to do this without changing all of my consuming code to use Java.lang.Long?

Furthermore,  is there a way to do an implicit conversion to a value class to allow random access to the ArrayList without allocating an extra object as above? Thanks a ton for any insight you might provide.

Comment: Could you show an example of code that does not work because of the problems you describe, and the errors that you encounter?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Scala has autoboxing, so much of the time a `scala.Long` is a `java.lang.Long`. This is almost always the case when the value is stored inside a collection like `Vector`. At present it is safe to do a `.asInstanceOf[Vector[scala.Long]]` to convert the type of the `Vector`, but this [could change in the future](http://scala-miniboxing.org/2014/06/27/miniboxing-roadmap.html).

A safer way is to explicitly convert the values. Scala has implicit conversions between `scala.Long` and `java.lang.Long`, but they won't convert collections of those types. However, you can combine them with `map` to convert, e.g. `.map(Long2long)` to convert a collection of `java.lang.Long` to a collection of `scala.Long`.

As for your second question, if you import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` instead of `JavaConverters` you will get a set of implicit conversions. However, the recommended way is it to use `JavaConverters`. It would also be more efficient in your case, because the wrapper only has to be created once.

If you really like to play fast and dangerous, you could write your own implicit conversion:

```
implicit def convArrayList(al: ArrayList[java.lang.Long]): Vector[Long] =
  al.asScala.map(Long2long)(collection.breakOut)
```

Comment: @DanGetz You're right, it was actually implicit conversions in `Predef` that were working the magic. I've changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Does that map implicitly create a new data structure when the elements are enumerated or is that somehow transparently accessing the abstracted ArrayList?

Comment: It creates a new data structure. You could write one to provide transparent access, but it would be more complicated.