# Safe cast of Scala collection containing primitives

Tags: java, scala, type-safety, scala-java-interop

I'm working on mixed Java-Scala projects, and quite often I need to convert collections.

When I want to convert a collection of primitives, I should be writing something like this

```
val coll: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val jColl = coll.map(v => Int.box(v)).asJava
```

However, I know that with both Java and Scala generic collections use boxed values, so I can safely avoid iterating with needless boxing and just write

```
val jColl = coll.asJava.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]]
```

However, compiler won't complain if I'll make a mistake in either collection type or element type.

Is there a type-safe way of doing this avoiding extra iteration? Is there at least a way to keep checks for collection type?

Comment: Why not `.asScala` ?

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620574/implicit-conversion-between-scala-long-and-java-lang-long-in-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't think of a way to avoid the `scala.Int` -> `java.lang.Integer` conversion being a bit manual or unsafe, but if you only implement it once and reuse it, it can pretty much eliminate the risk.

One approach might be:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
implicit class IntCollectionBoxer[C[_] <: java.lang.Iterable[_]](elems: C[Int]) {
  def asJavaBoxed: C[java.lang.Integer] = elems.asInstanceOf[C[java.lang.Integer]]
}
```

(repeat for Double and other types)

Then usage would be this, which is pretty hard to make a mistake with:

```
val jColl = coll.asJava.asJavaBoxed
```

You might wish to change the bound on `C` depending on your usage as well.

Comment: I think it's a good place for implicit def instead of implicit class. Anyway, accepting the answer for as long as better idea doesn't come out.